# Storing Ranges in an Array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to create an array whose objects are of type Range. But creating an array like below produces an error "Reference to generic type 'Range' requires arguments in <...>"

```
var ranges:Array<Range> = []
```

Basically, what I'm trying to accomplish is to create a list of ranges that will serve as a step function to generate a random type. I've done this without using array, but as I add more types I feel the need to just loop them over an array. My problem is that ranges somehow cannot be stored in an Array in Swift. Here's my old code that worked.

```
        let twisterUpperRange = UInt32(roundf(twisterRate * 1_000))
        let bombUpperRange = UInt32(roundf(bombRate * 1_000)) + twisterUpperRange
        let blindUpperRange = UInt32(roundf(blindRate * 1_000)) + bombUpperRange

        let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(1_000) + 1

        var powerupType:PowerupType
        switch randomNumber {
        case 0...twisterUpperRange:
            powerupType = PowerupType.TwisterType
        case twisterUpperRange...bombUpperRange:
            powerupType = PowerupType.BombType
        case bombUpperRange...blindUpperRange:
            powerupType = PowerupType.BlindType
        default:
            powerupType = PowerupType.NormalType
        }

        return powerupType
```

Comment: Are your ranges all going to be the same type (i.e. `UInt32`)? If so, you can just do: `var ranges: Array<Range<UInt32>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that Swift `Range` is generic a generic type on the type of the interval ends:

```
var ranges : Array<Range<UInt32>> = []
let blindRate = 0.3
let twisterRate = 0.5
let bombRate = 0.2
let twisterUpperRange = UInt32(twisterRate * 1_000)
let bombUpperRange = UInt32(bombRate * 1_000) + twisterUpperRange
let blindUpperRange = UInt32(blindRate * 1_000) + bombUpperRange
ranges.append(0...twisterUpperRange)
ranges.append(twisterUpperRange...bombUpperRange)
ranges.append(bombUpperRange...blindUpperRange)
print(ranges)
```

[Demo.](http://www.runswiftlang.com/s/9_fzmBBC)